Adding labels to items in enumerate environments in AucTeX
I'm trying to use the official AucTeX insertion mechanism to insert environments, it being official and all, but I'm having a really hard time getting into it. For instance, AucTeX automatically provides a template for an enumerate environment, but that template doesn't automatically add a reftex-label to the first item it inserts. Following the documentation and inspecting LaTeX-env-item and LaTeX-env-label I put the following into my init:
  (TeX-add-style-hook
   "latex"
   (lambda ()
     (LaTeX-add-environments
      '("enumerate" LaTeX-env-enumerate))))

  (defun LaTeX-env-enumerate (environment)
    "Insert ENVIRONMENT and the first item.
The first item is inserted by the function `LaTeX--env-item'."
    (LaTeX-insert-environment environment)
    (LaTeX--env-item environment)
    (LaTeX-label environment))

Positively speaking I can still insert environments, but negatively speaking it still doesn't insert a label. What am I doing wrong?

What exactly are you trying to achieve?  You want to have a \label after the first \item in every enumerate environment you enter?

@ArashEsbati Yes, a reftex-indexed label. For later items, a label is added automatically by cdlatex, but when I use AucTeX to insert the enumerate environment, the first item is not automatically labeled, that's what I'm trying to correct

You have to consider some aspects in your code:

AUCTeX doesn't have an entry for the enumerate environment in the variable LaTeX-label-alist, so you have to add one first
You have to give your function LaTeX-env-enumerate more arguments than the standard LaTeX-env-item, otherwise you will not replace it
You need to tweak the way you call LaTeX-label by using the second TYPE argument

Putting it together, something like this in your init file should work:
(defun LaTeX-env-enumerate (environment &rest _ignore)
  "Insert ENVIRONMENT and the first item.
The first item is inserted by the function `LaTeX--env-item' followed by
a label."
  (LaTeX-insert-environment environment)
  (LaTeX--env-item environment)
  (save-excursion (LaTeX-label environment 'environment)))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (TeX-add-style-hook
             "latex2e"
             (lambda ()
               (add-to-list 'LaTeX-label-alist
                            '("enumerate" . "item"))
               (LaTeX-add-environments
                '("enumerate" LaTeX-env-enumerate))))))

AUCTeX will pass the generation of label to RefTeX and inserts it after the first \item.
P.S. I'm not a fan of having this kind of stuff in init file.  You really should put your LaTeX customizations in a <name>.sty file and corresponding AUCTeX code in <name>.el in a directory where AUCTeX can find the library.
